# Change utm zones on a GeoDataFrame

Tags: python, coordinates, geopandas

I'm trying to change the crs of a geodataframe. When I try to:

> > > my_map.to_crs(4326)

I  get an error message:

> > > ProjError: x, y, z, and time must be same size

What do I do with this info, and how can I change the crs?

Inital crs info from geo dataframe is:
<Projected CRS: EPSG:25833>
Name: ETRS89 / UTM zone 33N
Axis Info [cartesian]:

- E[east]: Easting (metre)
- N[north]: Northing (metre)
  Area of Use:
- name: Europe - 12°E to 18°E and ETRS89 by country
- bounds: (12.0, 46.4, 18.01, 84.01)
  Coordinate Operation:
- name: UTM zone 33N
- method: Transverse Mercator
  Datum: European Terrestrial Reference System 1989
- Ellipsoid: GRS 1980
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich

Answer (score 0):

There is a [github issue](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/2874) with the same error, try updating PROJ and pyproj